# Unable to open database file error - creating login page using flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

*I am trying to create a login page for my website using Flask sqlalchemy and sqlite3 to create the login user database. I am able to get the website up and running just fine, but am unable to successfully create a user within my database. I have create a table for my sqlite3 database using DB browser, and I have confirmed that it has the columns names that I want it to have using the command terminal on my Mac.

Each time I try to create a user I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) 
unable to open database file
```

The error message says that this line of code is causing all of my issues:

File "/Users/milesvonherrmann/Desktop/project /Cuisine.py", line 73, in signup Open an interactive python shell in this framedb.session.commit()

I have attached my Cuisine.py file below. How can I get my database file to be recognized?*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, 
current_user



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisissupposedtobesecret!'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'sqlite:///c/Users/milesvonherrmann/Desktop/project/usertable.db'



bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String(80))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
  return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
  password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
  remember = BooleanField('remember me')

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
  email = StringField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email'), 
  Length(max=50)])
  username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
  password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
    #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
  form = RegisterForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
    new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return '<h1>New user has been created!</h1>'
    #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.email.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

return render_template('signup.html', form=form)

@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
  return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.username)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
  logout_user()
  return redirect(url_for('index'))

#if __name__ == '__main__':
  #app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another answer to this question.

I had the same problem and I found out something. First check the parent path in your console. In your case, if you put the whole path, then you need to put 4 "/".

So it would be like this:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'sqlite:////c/Users/milesvonherrmann/Desktop/project/usertable.db'
```

I suppose the C refers to the unit so you would need to add the column as well.

When you changed to `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///usertable.db'`

It worked because it only needs 3 "/" when using partial path. I also prefer this option my problem was that I had a different parent path and it was looking somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have wrong the config path for the database. Try this:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///usertable.db'
```

I am always doing it this way. Hope that it will work

Comment: I made this update to my code and I no longer get the "unable to access database file" error. But I do get this error:   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named password
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('mvonnn', 'mlsvonherrmann@gmail.com', 'sha256$efQhjPOI$739ac436aaf98a433d998deebd87500148bcb31596998db1472720a4ba5f9e66')]

Comment: My database is stored within my project folder, within that folder is also my python file, a templates folder for html code, a static folder for css code, and a folder called "_pycache_"(auto-generated, I did not create this).

Comment: @mvonherrmann24 I think I know where the problem is. You have maximum input lenght of password 80 characters, but after you hash the password it will get longer, i think. Try it first without hashing the password

Comment: This is weird, because the password it tried to insert is exactly 80 characters long, so it should work.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as last time, but the error actually prints out the password I entered in this time.       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named password
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('mvonnn', 'mlsvonherrmann@gmail.com', 'Claremont9090')] I will post my code changes.

Comment: 'def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        #if user:
            #if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                #login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                #return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))'

Comment: 'def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return '<h1>New user has been created!</h1>' '

Comment: You are doing everything right on the class inserting side. Last thing I would try is: delete the database.db file. Then open python console in command line by typing python. Then execute `from cuisine.py import db` and then execute `db.create_all()`. This just recreates the database

Comment: Ok,I'll try that. By deleting the database do you mean removing the line of code where the database is stored? Or should I actually delete the database file from my project folder?

Comment: Delete the file